# how to add a small image and a container of the image on top frame yet control background color of the container

Tags: css, background-image, background-color

I have a html page that is separated by top, left, and right frames via css not via html frameset tag. I want to add a small image to a top frame yet be able to control background color of the top frame. The problem I ran into is I see an image added, but no background color I specified.

css file

```
#foo {
    background-color : blue;
    background-image : url("foo.png");
    width : 100px;
    height : 50px;
}
```

html file

```
<html>
    ...<body>
         <div id="foo"></div>
    ...</body></html>
```

[update with an answer]

After reading replies from Marcelo and Paulie_D to this question, I realized that what I had to do (first correcting my question and adding an answer here).

```
<html>
    ...<body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="foo"></div>
        </div>


#container {
    background-color : blue;
}

#foo {
    background-image : url('foo.png');
    width : 100px;
    height : 50px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The background color will still be set for all the areas of the element not covered by the image. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emXOLw Could you be more specific in what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Marcelo: forgive me if my question was not clear. i thought i could use both properties (background-color and image) however when i have only background-color, i see the expected color, but if I add background-image together i only see the image but no background-color.

Comment: Are you actually using a `.png` file that has transparency...it's not automatic with `png`files.

Comment: @Paulie_D: oh, let me double check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely provided the image has transparency..

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url(http://www.clker.com/cliparts/1/c/c/f/13902170611226395134cat_png_by_dbszabo1-d3dn2c8.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>My Cat</h1>
</div>
```